# С Activity добавить фрагмент в контейнер другой Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть MainActivity в которой есть FrameLayout контейнер для фрагментов. В другой Activity, что наследует FragmentActivity выполняются некоторые операции, на основе которых редактируется фрагмент (который еще нигде не отображен). Так же в этой Activity есть кнопка, по нажатию которой, нужно чтобы фрагмент добавился в контейнер на MainActivity.
Когда я реализую простое добавление фрагмента в контейнер, через FragmentManager, то получаю ошибку: No view found for id... fragment. Почему ошибка происходит, мне известно.

Как реализовать эту штуку?

Comment: какую штуку? Какой результат нужен?

Comment: Вам нужно передавать в другое активити данные (через интент или onActivityResult) и на основе их окрывать свой фрагмент вызвав эту активити, а не пытаться из одной активити манипулировать другой, потому что активити, которая не на переднем плане, в общем случае, не существует, ее виджеты не инициализированы, а работа остановлена

Comment: Вы правы, и это так просто, ведь вытекает из простой теории. Спасибо, попробую!